# C# string literal as a command line argument using @

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, literals

This is probably a simple error on my part but I'm having issues reading a string argument that begins with @ in the context of `XML`.

For example:

```
program.exe file.xml @attribute
```

the `@attribute` string is the attribute that I need to check for in a join:

```
var testjoin = from x in tree1 join y in tree2 on (string)x.Attribute(args[2]) equals (string)y.Attribute("Order") select x
```

but I keep throwing errors "name cannot begin with the '@' character..." from when I try to pass it directly to `x.Attribute()`

Would someone be able to help me solve this?

EDIT: 
The `XML` content of the file is irrelevant. This is for assignment purposes but it is a simple file of Customers that I am comparing with a file of Orders.

The header of the file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The `@attribute` was literally `@CustomerID` and I cannot alter how it is passed into my program. I can alter how I process it, so if there is another method I can use to perform a join passing that in as an attribute, I can change that.

Comment: Show us the XML content.

Comment: Is there a reason why the attribute starts with an "@" symbol? XML is very strict in terms of syntax, and "@attribute" is not valid, but "attribute" would be.

Comment: I can't edit the XML file content nor the command line arguments :(

Comment: @user3431504 Does the XML contains attribute named `@CustomerID`? If this is the case, then it is not a well-formed XML, and can't be parsed using standard XML parser

Comment: It contains CustomerID, without the @ symbol. The @symbol is just in the command line argument, I assume to make it a string literal, and I can't figure out why or how to make use of it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ["C# string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)" and a "command line argument" live in different worlds, they have nothing to do with each other.

A (verbatim or regular) string literal is evaluated at compile time by the C# compiler. The '@' sign is an escape character used for verbatim string literals that (a.o.) tells the compiler to treat certain characters literally instead of as escape characters. E.g. `@"hello\tworld"` will compile into a string with an actual backslash followed by `t`, while `"hello\tworld"` turns `\t` into a tab.

A command line argument is passed in at runtime, so it can not be treated as a string literal. Which makes it your responsibility to deal with the '@' character in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I was going nuts trying to figure this out. This is simple and makes sense!